# Chrome extension not receiving Firebase Cloud Messages

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

Something really weird is happening with me. Yesterday atfernoon I realized my chrome extension wasn't receiving Firebase Cloud Messages sent by my server. I've tried to create a new Chrome Extension with nothing more than the GCM API and a simple server page with the message sender, but it still not working.

Suddenly it started working again and I received ALL the messages that I sent in that period!! I thought it was a server issue and ok. Today in the morning it was working perfectly. BUT AGAIN, in the afternoon, it stopped! I don't know what to do, I've been using Chrome extension with the GCM API for months and it have never happened before.

My extension:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_myextension__",
  "version": "1.3",
  "icons": {
    "128": "images/my-icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "gcm",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "default_locale" : "en"
}
```

background.js (yes I copied from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client))

```
function registerCallback(registrationId) {   
   console.log(registrationId);   
   if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    return;   
   }
}

var senderIds = ["MY-SENDER-ID"]; 
chrome.gcm.register(senderIds, registerCallback);

chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {    
  console.log(message);  
});
```

My server:

```
$registration_id = '...'; 
$key = '...'; 
$message = '{"collapse_key":"'.time().'","data":{"message":"hello world"},"priority":"high","registration_ids":["'.$registration_id.'"]}';

$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization:key=' . $key );

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

As a result from my curl, I'm getting always success.
I'm pretty sure I'm sending the message to the right registration ID.
Can somebody help me??

Comment: I'm also having kind of similar issues, any update fro your side?

Comment: No updates here

Comment: @DMkitten I'm trying to setup a chrome extension that can receive messages from Firebase Cloud Messaging - and I'm unsure of how to setup the registration and token-getting in the background.js file. Do you have any links/resources on how you set up your extension? Thanks!

Comment: any update here? Also @WayWay anything on this

Comment: @WayWay If you were able to do "registration and token-getting in the background.js file" can you help me with that.